# Anyone know the schematic of the audio connectors on Asus' Xonar dx 7.1?

Tags: audio

One of the connectors' internal contacts is broken, so i have no channels 6 and 7. I'd like to replace the connector (7 pins) with a 5 pin or another 7 pin connector, but i have a devil of a time finding out what where to connect.

Edit: to better formulate the question: channel 6-7 connector is broken. The connector has 7 pins; it may have switched contacts. This is why by simply soldering 3 wires to the main contacts did not bear results. I am, therefore, looking for someone who may have experience with these kinds of connectors.

Comment: 'Jacks' have one pin. Any more & it's not a jack. All the pictures of this i can see online show it has several regular jacks [presumably standard TRS] rather than one multi-pin. We need a lot more info, pictures etc to even begin to be able to help.

Comment: The trs jack is in a plastic housing, like a small box. The box has 7 pins. I' try to make some photos. J.

Comment: Sorry guys, this is my very first time on this site. I ran through every possible link in the Help section, but nowhere did i find anything about uploading photos. Can you enlighten me, please?

Comment: This is a female jack. I am NOT going to replace the jack, because there is no way to find a replacement. I have a regular 5 pin jack that i want to wire into the pin wholes of the bad jack on the pcb of the card.

Comment: You can upload a picture to something like imgur.com and edit the question to include the link to the picture.

Comment: Hi again!  I addressed my question specifically to members whom i was hoping to have delt with this problem on THIS particular card. The female jack in question is proprietary to Asus, so it's not replaceable. So, IFF there's someone who knows this card well, please address my question. I don't want to waste anyone's time.

Comment: Thank you all. I DID do all that. If one takes a look at similar jacks present in Switchceaft's very long and exhaustive catalog, these kinds of seven pin jacks have switched interior contacts. I misspoke about the 'internal' contacts. It's the Left channel, also serving as securing contact. It sits in top of the box, clearly showing its function. However, the rest are inside of the box, seemingly intact. You're right,though, more testing is necessary. I tried to repair this contact, but i can't find the special elastic brass alloy for it. Traces? No, the board being covered w thick paint.

Comment: Ah, right, so it's a chassis-mounted jack socket. That wasn't at all clear to start with.  If you've unmounted it have you tried simple continuity tests to establish the fault? Jack sockets are pretty difficult to damage internally. Excessive force is more likely to break them away from the PCB, or damage the PCB itself.

Comment: For the future; when asked for clarifictions, "did you try this" etc. it's better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769814/edit) the question itself than answering in comments. This way everything relevant is readily available, and the question reflects the exact current situation. Trying to dig out the info from extended comments is a pain in the as...tutely named lower back. TBH , as we're talking about schematics of a specific board and hardware repairs, I think this question is much better fit for [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Answer (score 0):

Ladies and gentlemen, too much ink about not much. I owe you all a big apology. Turns out that my tests of the jack were good, to begin with. The receiver was configured to 5.1 instead of 7.1. I did everything by the book to begin with, overlooking a prosaic element of my endeavor. The only excuse I have is that my system is very complex, integrating a plethora of audio-video subsystems.

Comment: LOL :-D Thanks. I don't think I'm not the only one who kinda needed the reminder that "Is it plugged in" et co. are still valid questions :-)

Comment: Thanks, Peregrino69 :))